# Remove underline from ::first-letter

Tags: css, pseudo-element, typography, text-decorations

I'm trying underline all letters except the first. I attempted to remove the underline from the first letter via `::first-letter` without success. Why doesn't that work here?

```
<a class="sample underline letter-underline-none"
   href="https://twitter.com/ryanve"
>@ryanve</a>
```

How can I remove the underline without changing this markup? [I made a codepen](https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/GOqjNM) with this CSS.

```
.letter-underline::first-letter,
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.letter-underline-none::first-letter,
.underline-none {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sample {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration:

> Text decorations are drawn across descendant text elements. This means that **if an element specifies a text decoration, then a child element can't remove the decoration**.

(emphasis mine). Of course, in your case you don't have a true child element (merely a first-letter pseudo-element), but the same logic applies.

That said, some experimentation suggests a child element can add its *own* underline (covering up the ancestor's), and then specify the color of that underline using the `text-decoration-color`. So you could potentially hack together your desired visual effect, in most cases, by writing something like

```
.letter-underline-none::first-letter {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #FFF;
}
```

(adjusting the `#FFF` part to match the intended background color). I don't think I'd recommend that, though — it seems too likely to have weird edge cases that look worse than the all-underline effect to begin with.

Comment: Nice answer! That technique seems reasonable if using CSS variables https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/JOKKJz but an extra element does seem safer for this case especially due the `@`

Comment: Brilliant hack!